# array manipulation with circshift octave / matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

1) I'm trying to shift an array's (outer cells) first and last cell  **inward** at the same time.  Here's an inward animation of what I'm trying to do with the array 
[inward animation](http://youtu.be/65iu4rajIEQ).  As you can see the outer cells are moving inward (from the ends) at the same time

Here's a pic but the animation shows it much better please note the array could have either an even or odd amount of cells

```
Inner rotation steps
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
4 1 2 3 6 7 5
3 4 1 2 7 5 6
```

[image: Inward direction]

2) I'm trying to shift an array's middle cells **outward** using circshift (which I think is fastest) at the same time.
Here's an outward animation of what I'm trying to do also
[outward animation](http://youtu.be/hHUqWoRmvbk).  As you can see the middle of the signal is moving outward (left and right) at the same time.

Here's a pic but the animation shows it much better please note the array could have either an even or odd amount of cells

```
Outer rotation steps
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 1 7 5 6
3 4 1 2 6 5 7
```

[image]

```
Example: inward
a = (1:7)
y=circshift(A,[0 -2]) %shift end of array inward
3   4   5   6   7   1   2

a = (1:7)
y=circshift(A,[0 2]) %shift beginning of array inward
6   7   1   2   3   4   5
```

*Not to sure how to do the middle cells shifting outward using circshift or the outer cells shifting inward at the same time*

I'm not sure about how to start circshift from the center and move the array outwards / inwards to get this effect.

Please note I'm not trying to get this equation I'm just trying to get the arrays to move in the same way.  I'm using octave 3.8.1 which is compatible with matlab.

Comment: so if `a = 1:7` then you want to shift everything inwards so after one shift you desire... `? 1 2 3 5 6 7 ?`? What goes where the `?`s are? If you had an even number then I would guess you'd want `1:8` to shift to `4 1 2 3 6 7 8 5` right? Some manually worked numeric examples would be very helpful here

Comment: @Dan that was exactly my problem with the numerics I could visualize it using animation but I would get confused with doing it numerically, I wasn't sure what would go next, hence me making the animations showing exactly what I'm trying to do with the array. http://youtu.be/65iu4rajIEQ and
http://youtu.be/hHUqWoRmvbk

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want exactly but you can use `circshift` on matrices. If each side your signal takes a column of matrix you can use a single call and then simple flatten it (you will have to reverse one of the signals though when creating that matrix). An alternative is to simple shift indices to your signal (also in the shape of the matrix).

Comment: @Dan I added some numerics hopefully that helps

Comment: Why not divide the array into two parts and then use `circshift` on them individually like `circshift(part1,[0 1])` and `circshift(part2,[0 -1])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = 1:7;

split = ceil(numel(A)/2);

n = 2;
A(1:split) = circshift(A(1:split), [0, n]);
A(split+1:end) = circshift(A(split+1:end), [0, -n]);
```

Put the last three lines in a loop if you like. Also just change the signs of `n` for inwards or outwards

Comment: For this to work in octave I needed to adjust these 2 lines
A(1:split) = circshift(A(1:split), [0 n]);

A(split+1:end) = circshift(A(split+1:end), [0 -n]);  thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

what about constructing new indices instead of using circshift:

```
A = 1:7;

halfLen = ceil(length(A)/2); % or use ceil to 
idcsOutward = [2:halfLen,1,length(A),(halfLen+1):(length(A)-1)];

B1 = A(idcsOutward)
B2 = B1(idcsOutward)

% and inward:
idcsInward = [halfLen,1:(halfLen-1),(halfLen+2):length(A),halfLen+1];

C1 = A(idcsInward)
C2 = C1(idcsInward)
```

Result is:

```
B1 =
     2     3     4     1     7     5     6

B2 =
     3     4     1     2     6     7     5

C1 =
     4     1     2     3     6     7     5

C2 =
     3     4     1     2     7     5     6
```